# few css issues on Internet Explorer 7 (Ie7) using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I know that bootstrap 3 is not compatible with IE7. However, I need to make it workable for the form I am building. This is not responsive.. just need to work nicely with IE7 including the error messages...

As you can see by comparing it on IE7 and any other nice browsers like Chrome, the state and age fields are not aligned side by side as it should be. The 2nd tick box is not aligned to the right of the 1st tick box... and there is a black line over the enter details button. Any help please?

Even though IE7 has extra low share, it is something that the client wants. I love using Bootstrap and he doesnt want any responsiveness... and doesnt even want %/em etc.. wants fixed width. Hence the code has fixed width.

To answer another query from below, I was hoping bootstrap3 has some kind of css patch that makes it workable for IE7 or atleast direct me on how to fix the issues listed here. HOwever I did end up fixing them. So thanks guys.

Link is here

http://staging.serviceportal.com.au/service05/discovery_2014.do

I solved the issue as below

```
body .container {
    width: 900px
}
body input {
    height:20px !important;
}
/*.form-control{
    behavior: url(http://localhost/On%20Going/Discovery/January2014/discovery/web/pie/PIE.htc); 
}*/
body select {
    height: 34px !important;
    width: 120px !important;
}

.firstName, .lastName, .age{
    margin-bottom:15px
}

.col-sm-6 {
width: 50%;
}
.tick1{
    padding-left:0px;
    width:160px !important
}

.discoveryButton, .discovertMandatoryText{
    float:left !important
}
.discoveryButton{
    width:154px !important
}
.discoveryButton #submit{
    text-indent:-9999px;
    display:block
}
.discovertMandatoryText{
    width:139px !important
}
.col-sm-7.tick2.has-pretty-child{
    padding-left:0px;
    width:270px;
    margin-left:150px;
    margin-top:-70px;
}
.age-state .age{
    width:118px;
}
.email{
    margin-top:10px;
}
.stars{
    margin-left:10px;
}
select.state{
    margin-left:60px
}
.state .stars{
    margin-left:35px !important
}
```

So what I basically did is to look in firebug in a nicer browser like Firefox and get the margin, padding and width needed. I just copied those into the IE7.css file. And it worked. Yeep it is not responsive in ie7. However, by doing what I did, I was able to make it look nicer in IE7. I guess if someone is using bootstrap3, then do look at the padding/margin/width where it is breaking in IE7. Then take those values and add in IE7 only css file. Hope it works and helps someone

Comment: Bootstrap isn't compatible with IE7. Nothing you can do (short of applying a patch to the code) will fix this. IE7 has negligible market share. Why, why, why target a crappy and dying browser?

Comment: Firstly I know it is not compatible. And 2ndly that is one of my job duties.. Any idea how to solve this? Any patch is ok as long as the layout gets fixed

Comment: There may not be a patch - in that case, you would have to build one yourself. As the other commenters say though, IE7 is near extinct and also no longer supported (and thus no longer safe to use). The only reason for still supporting it that I can think of is a company internal network - in that case, upgrading the client machines that need to see this to a newer version of Internet Explorer may be not only the prudent thing to do generally, but also the easiest way out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely have to have IE7 compatibility, use a conditional statement to target IE7 and add styles as needed to fix issues you have:

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_css_dir/ie7.css" />
    - OR - 
    include your IE7 specific css here...
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I know that is what I was doing so.. I just need those three alignment issues fixed.. couldnt figure out quick soln for those three

Comment: Sorry but can't help you actually fix the bugs as it's IE7. Also, just looking at your example and you might have issues coming from the fact that you are incorrectly using Boostrap. You should not be setting ANY fixed widths for block level elements (example: .leftside). If you are trying to limit the overall size, use .container OR worst case scenario, use max-width instead of just width. This will dramatically improve what you have in terms of making your page responsive, which is is not at the moment..

Comment: We do not need to make this responsive. We just need to make this workable in like the smallest amount of time

Comment: Well even though I hate to see iE7 exist in any form, my client wants it to be alive.. what a day